# Parsing XML page to read content

Tags: c#, xml

I want to read the url in the XML Page URLString, and I wrote the following code:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(URLString);
var list = from y in xelement.Descendants(atom + "entry")
           select new {
               Link = y.Element(atom + "link").Attribute("href").Value
           };
```

The output of list in the debug is 25 url.

I want to get the items into `list`. How can I loop through the list to get the items inside it using for, while, foreach, etc.?

Comment: What? I don't understand what you're asking. Could you clarify your question by listing what's happening and what you'd like to be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I've worked with LINQ, but I think you can do this:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(URLString);
var items = from y in xelement.Descendants(atom + "entry")
  select y.Element(atom + "link").Attribute("href").Value;
var list = items.ToList();
```

At this point, `list` will be of type `List<string>` and you can do whatever you want with it.